Zip a folder with password protection at folder level using Java
I'm trying out an automation which needs to zip a folder and password protect it at folder level.
I used zip4j and able to achieve the password protection at file level only.
Here is my code which does the zipping and password protection at file level.

import java.io.File;

import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.EncryptionMethod;

public class ZipWithPasswordExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Source folder to be zipped
        String sourceFolderPath = "<source folder>";
        // Destination zip file path
        String destinationZipFilePath = "<destination folder>.zip";
        // Password for encryption
        String password = "<Password>";

        try {
            // Create a new ZipFile object
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destinationZipFilePath, password.toCharArray());

            // Parameters for creating the zip file
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
            parameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.ZIP_STANDARD);

            // Add folder to the zip file
            File sourceFolder = new File(sourceFolderPath);
            zipFile.addFolder(sourceFolder, parameters);

            System.out.println("Folder successfully zipped and encrypted!");
        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


I have tried searching for other libraries to use or other ways but couldn't achieve this.
I also tried using apache commons library which does the job as: test.zip -> tempfolder.zip (password protection is done at this level) -> test folder -> test1.txt , test2.txt etc.,
import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.EncryptionMethod;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.CompressionLevel;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class APACHECOMMONS2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sourceFolder = "<sourcepath>";
         String zipFilePath = "<destination_path>";
        String password = "<password>";
        
        System.out.println("source folder: " + sourceFolder);
        System.out.println("zip file path: " + zipFilePath);
        System.out.println("password: " + password);

        try {
            zipFolderWithPassword(sourceFolder, zipFilePath, password);
            System.out.println("Created password-protected zip file: " + zipFilePath);
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void zipFolderWithPassword(String sourceFolderPath, String zipFilePath, String password) throws IOException, ZipException {
        // Step 1: Create a temporary zip file using Apache Commons Compress
        File tempZipFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".zip");
        System.out.println(tempZipFile.getPath());
        try (ZipArchiveOutputStream archiveOutputStream = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempZipFile))) {
            File folderToZip = new File(sourceFolderPath);
            addFolderToZip(archiveOutputStream, folderToZip, folderToZip.getName());
        }

        // Step 2: Create the final password-protected zip file using Zip4j
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath, password.toCharArray());
        ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
        parameters.setCompressionLevel(CompressionLevel.NORMAL);
        parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        parameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES);

        zipFile.addFile(tempZipFile, parameters);

        // Step 3: Clean up the temporary zip file
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(tempZipFile);
    }

    private static void addFolderToZip(ZipArchiveOutputStream archiveOutputStream, File folder, String basePath) throws IOException {
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                String entryName = basePath + "/" + file.getName();
                System.out.println("file name: " +entryName);
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                      System.out.println("file is a directory");
                   addFolderToZip(archiveOutputStream, file, entryName);
                } else {
                      System.out.println("not a directory");
                    ArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(file, entryName);
                    archiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry((ZipArchiveEntry) entry);
                    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, archiveOutputStream);
                    }
                   archiveOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I found certain relevant questions from the past and tried out the solution but it seems to be old and many solutions that I tried used methods which are deprecated now.
It would be helpful if someone can suggest a solution how this protection can be done at folder level or if there are any other libraries which can do the job.
Thanks in advance.

There are no folders in zip files. Programs presenting a hierarchical folder structure derive it from the entry names.

By folder I mean the actual zip file. Hierarchy: mainfolder.zip file -> other folders -> actual files. for example: test.zip -> test1 (folder) -> test.txt(actual file). Here, using my code, the password protection is done at test.txt level while I want it at the test.zip level itself.

@Shanjana M  , Use your program code to compress and encrypt a directory and generate an encrypted zip file. In Linux, use the command line unzip your-enc-zip. It will ask for the password. It means that it has been encrypted for the zip file. So Did I understand it wrong?

Thank you, but my question is more about applying password protection to the zip file. I'm able to achieve the password protection partially i.e. in this way --> test.zip -> tempfolder.zip (password protection is done at this level) -> test folder -> test1.txt , test2.txt etc.  I would like to know if it can be achieved this way --> test.zip (password protection at this level) -> test folder -> test1.txt , test2.txt etc. (eliminating the temp folder)
